# Does Packet Sniffer work inside a Titan?

Tags: titanfall

I'm curious if the Packet Sniffer burn card ("You automatically generate Active Radar Pulses periodically") works inside a Titan.  Ordinarily you can't activate pilot abilities inside a Titan (or you end up activating the Titan's tactical ability), but this being automatic, perhaps?

It would be helpful when doing Last Titan Standing maps with my friend to see what building pesky pilots on foot might be hiding in.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure it does, but I'll test it out to make sure!

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't have a screenshot handy, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packet Sniffer, and Echo Vision, both work when you're in a Titan! The range seems to be slightly decreased, but that could just be due to my lack of experience using the Active Radar Pulse (I hate it so much).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0FtC.jpg)[image: Echo Vision being used in a Titan]

I didn't get a screenshot of Packet Sniffer (the game was very hectic!), but I did grab one with Echo Vision active. You can see the orange radar pulse in the freehand circle.